# Get counts for every factor in one column of data.table broken out by two other columns

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a `data.table` containing a column, `DT$Locale`

that has the following entries:

```
DT[,unique(Locale)]

downstream                upstream                  intergenic                intron                    intron,nc                 regulatory                synonymous               
non_coding_exon,nc        5_prime_UTR               splice,5_prime_UTR        splice,intron             missense                  3_prime_UTR               splice,intron,nc         
splice,synonymous         splice_donor              synonymous,NMD            mature_miRNA              splice_donor,nc           splice_acceptor           3_prime_UTR,NMD          
stop_gained               missense,NMD              5_prime_UTR,NMD           intron,NMD                splice,intron,NMD         splice,non_coding_exon,nc missense,splice          
splice_acceptor,nc        coding_sequence,NMD       missense,splice,NMD       stop_lost                 initiator_codon           splice_acceptor,NMD
```

I have two other columns as well, having the following formats:

```
DT[,unique(Cohort)]
[1] CEU   Lupus RA    YRI  RALoci

DT[,unique(Locus)]

 [1] 1.110927656.111927656  1.194335780.195335780  1.217775877.218775877  1.236880267.237880267  1.85471701.86471701    10.52963302.53963302   10.6118896.7118896    
 [8] 10.74879027.75879027   11.20046869.21046869   12.37676238.38676238   12.38077040.39077040   13.92438484.93438484   14.47539055.48539055   14.89244697.90244697  
[15] 14.98090299.99090299   14.98556636.99556636   15.101213744.102213744 15.47426024.48426024   16.13885034.14885034   16.27399400.28399400   16.48056833.49056833  
[22] 16.5898498.6898498     16.63172805.64172805   16.76469520.77469520   16.86513832.87513832   17.4148334.5148334     18.4824309.5824309     18.54958827.55958827  
[29] 2.146859650.147859650  2.229978358.230978358  2.86605444.87605444    20.19570642.20570642   22.39592645.40592645   3.41789975.42789975    3.7782962.8782962     
[36] 3.85190848.86190848    4.141037599.142037599  4.29959034.30959034    5.128060465.129060465  5.65898794.66898794    5.7513893.8513893      6.56405042.57405042   
[43] 7.124946062.125946062  8.18012618.19012618    9.28933416.29933416    9.87628311.88628311
```

I wish to get a count of the type of each entry in `DT$Locale` for each combination of `DT$Cohort` and `DT$Locus`.

It seemed to me the that libary `data.table` represented an effective way to do this, so I tried things like:

`DT[,sum(unique(Locale)),by="Locus,Cohort"]`, but this of returns an error - it seems to me there is likely an easy way to do this using lapply, but I have not hit on the correct syntax yet, can anyone offer a solution?

Note: in response to posts:

```
RALociDT[,list(count=length(unique(Locale3))),by="Locus,Cohort"]
                     Locus Cohort count
  1: 1.110927656.111927656    CEU    14
  2: 1.110927656.111927656  Lupus    15
  3: 1.110927656.111927656     RA    14
  4: 1.110927656.111927656    YRI    13
  5: 1.194335780.195335780    CEU     4
 ---                                   
180:   9.28933416.29933416    YRI     4
181:   9.87628311.88628311    CEU    11
182:   9.87628311.88628311  Lupus    10
183:   9.87628311.88628311     RA     9
184:   9.87628311.88628311    YRI    11
```

Returns the number of items in the list that appear, not the count of how many times each one that does appear occurs (by Locus and Cohort).

Comment: @David Arenburg - thank you for helping me to edit. Could you help me understand what you did and why so I do not make the same mistakes again?

Comment: It is always best to show the error message and also post the actual data set using `dput`. But my guess is that the error is caused because you can't sum uniques as it is a `character` type vector, rather than numeric. Try `DT[,length(unique(Locale)),by="Locus,Cohort"]` maybe?

Comment: I suggest instead of describing what your data looks like you come up with a **small reproducible example** and present desired output for that example. That way you'll get much better responses and will also reduce the amount of miscommunication that happens when words you say don't mean the same thing for you as they do for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `DT[,list(count=length(unique(Locale))),by=c("Locus","Cohort")]`

Trying to `sum` the unique values of Locale when you want the `length` of the vector of unique values.

Comment: Firstly, this syntax does work:   by="Locus,Cohort"

And also, length(Unique(Locale))) returns the number of items in the list, by Cohort and Locus ... but what I want is the number of time each appears, not how many of them appear.

Thanks very much for your answer

Comment: your desired output is unclear. Please post a sample of what the desired output should look like.

Answer (score -1):

You've confused people by not making clear the difference between "number of times each appears" and "how many of them appear". To most of us that sounds like the same thing. Perhaps you simply want to add `Locale` to the grouping vector:

```
 DT[, table(Locale, Locus, Cohort)]
```

So that would count the number of times each `Locale`-type appears within each Locus and Cohort that has any representative.